# function returns None but it should returns a string , might be very silly

Tags: python

I have so many times checked this function in new python file separately there they works but when I run them in my python script , the returns 'None'

```
       print("message ==> ||" + user_message + "||")
        print(str(user_message))
        return str(user_message)

def not_quit(number_of_games_loss):
    message = str(newMessageFromUser(number_of_games_loss))
    print(message)
```

it should returns 5 , as u can see I am printing user_message to conform what It will return but then too , when I can the function and print it . it prints "None"

### OUTPUT

```
688
message ==> ||5||
5
None

||||
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'

|||
game is already started , PLAY !!! PLAY !!! PLAY!!!  or to quit send message 'quit'
```

### MY full code CODE

u can remove all inner_HTML part and write  `inner_HTML = str(5)` because that it worksing fine i have tested it .

```
def newMessageFromUser(number_of_games_loss ,AFK_TIME = 30):
    if AFK_TIME == 30:
        sleep(3)
    inner_HTML =  browser.find_element_by_class_name("VUU41")
    inner_HTML = inner_HTML.get_attribute('innerHTML')

    i = inner_HTML[len(inner_HTML) - 100 : ]
    user_message = str(i[i.find('''hjZTB"><span>''') + len('''hjZTB"><span>''') : i.find('''</span></div></div></div>''')])
    oi = inner_HTML[len(inner_HTML) - 1310 : ] 
    oi_1 = oi.find('''</a>''')
    if oi_1 != -1:
        print(oi_1)
    
    if oi_1 == -1:
        afk = AFK_TIME - 1
        sleep(1)
        if AFK_TIME == 0:
            sendMessage("⏱⏱  u have been kicked out of game because u where AFK_TIME for a long time  " , browser)
            print("⏱⏱ user have been kicked out of game because u where AFK_TIME for a long time  ")
            number_of_games_loss +=1
            saveData(number_of_games,number_of_games_loss,number_of_games_won,username,data_path)
            exit()
        d = afk/5
        if d in range(1,1000) and afk != 0:
          print("no message, AFK_TIME for " + str((afk - 30)).replace("-","")  + "sec" )
        newMessageFromUser(number_of_games_loss , AFK_TIME=afk )
    else:
        user_message = user_message.replace(" ","")
        print("message ==> ||" + user_message + "||")
        print(str(user_message))
        return str(user_message)



# userWillingToPlay game loop 
def not_quit(number_of_games_loss):
    message = str(newMessageFromUser(number_of_games_loss))
    print(message)
    try: 
        m = int(message)
        if( 1 <= m) and (m <= 7):
            player_move = int(m)
            return player_move
        else:
            sendMessage("invalid row number ",browser)
    except Exception as e:
        print("\n||||")
        print(e)
        print("\n|||")
        if "quit" in message:
            number_of_games_loss += 1
            saveData(number_of_games ,number_of_games_loss , number_of_games_won , username , data_path)
            sendMessage("Game quit's ☠‍♂️" , browser)
            print("game Over exiting .py file")
            exit()
        else:
            print("game is already started , PLAY !!! PLAY !!! PLAY!!!  or to quit send message 'quit' ")
            sendMessage("game is already started , PLAY !!! PLAY !!! PLAY!!!  or to quit send message 'quit' " , browser)
            not_quit(number_of_games_loss)

player_move = not_quit(number_of_games_loss)
```

### **THANKS A LOT FOR HELPING ME IN ADVANCE**

and sorry if its a silly problem

Comment: You don't return anything in `if oi_1 == -1:`

Comment: As @TedKleinBergman said, you called `newMessageFromUser()` recursively but didn't return anything

Comment: there i added else statement

Comment: @sakshamrai, but your code may flow through that if and not else. In that case it will not return anything

Comment: but u know it oi_1 not -1 because in out put it prints  "message ==> ||5||
5 " and it will only print that if the program Executus else statement

Comment: The if block calls the function `newMessageFromUser()` again recursively. It can happen that in the recursive call the code flowed through that else block and printing those messages. But when it return in that if block, the code will return nothing. To debug you can just put a print in that if block after call to `newMessageFromUser()` and check yourself

Comment: Also, don't confuse `print` and `return`; the former only writes a value to standard output, while the latter actually produces a return value. The interactive interpreter confuses the issue by always printing the value of an expression.

Comment: @kuro so can u please tell what changes i should do to return what it prints in `user_message` ,

Comment: @sakshamrai, change `newMessageFromUser(number_of_games_loss , AFK_TIME=afk )` to `return newMessageFromUser(number_of_games_loss , AFK_TIME=afk )`